# Is there a R function (or any way) to color code all numeric values within a single string?

Tags: string, colors, extract, numeric, stringr

I successfully manage to color code certain words within a string.

However, I am unable to color code ALL numeric values within that same tring.

I want all the numeric values within the string (example: 1, 2.3, 4, 6.87) to be of the same color (example: blue)

I am all ears to any solution, thank you so much for your help.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(crayon)
library(stringr)
library(readr)

# creating the string/vector # ALL GOOD HERE

text <- tolower(c("Kyste simple inférieur de
56 mm. Aorto-bi-iliaque en
5,9cm. Artères communes de 19mm et
de 87mm. 120mm stable.")) #tolower is removing capital letters#

# individuate words # ALL SEEMS GOOD HERE #
unique_words <- function(x) {
purrr::map(.x = x,
        .f = ~ unique(base::strsplit(x = ., split = " ")[[1]],
                        collapse = " "))
}

# creating a dataframe with crayonized text # ALL SEEMS GOOD HERE #
df <- 
tibble::enframe(unique_words(x = text)) %>%
tidyr::unnest() %>%

# here you can specify the color/word combinations you need # PROBLEM SEEMS TO BE HERE #
dplyr::mutate(.data = .,
            value2 = dplyr::case_when(value == "aorto-bi-iliaque" ~ crayon::green(value),                                       
                                    value == gsub(".*(\\b\\d+\\b).*", "\\1", text) ~          crayon::blue(value), **# Here is where I need help #**
    TRUE ~ value)) %>%
dplyr::select(., -value) 


# printing the text
print(cat(df$value2))
```

[image]

This is what it gives me, the word is correctly color coded but all the numeric value are still unchanged

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're wanting something like this:

```
unique_words <- function(x) {
    map(.x = x,
        .f = ~ unique(base::strsplit(x = ., split = " |\n")[[1]],
                        collapse = " "))
}

df <- enframe(unique_words(x = text)) %>%
    unnest(value) %>%
    mutate(value2 = case_when(value == "aorto-bi-iliaque" ~ green(value),                               
                              grepl(pattern = "\\d+", x = value) ~  str_replace_all(value, "([0-9\\,\\.])", blue("\\1")),
                              TRUE ~ value)) %>%
    select(., -value) 


# printing the text
print(cat(df$value2))
```

Output:
[image: output]